# Office365 get messages and filter who from

Tags: ios, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get messages from office365 and filter the From property.
If I don't do the filter part, I get the messages as expected. I just don't know what to put in the filter string...

This is what i've done:

```
MSOutlookFolderFetcher *folderFetcher = [[self.client getMe] getFoldersById:folderID];
NSURLSessionTask *task = [[[[[[folderFetcher getMessages] top:10] skip:0] orderBy:@"DateTimeReceived"] filter:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From.EmailAddress.Address eq '%@'",emailAddress]] read:^(NSArray<MSOutlookMessage> *messages, MSODataException *error) {


    completion(messages);
}];

[task resume];
```

I get the following error:

Code: 400

Meassage: "Cannot resolve the OData request URL."

This is the link to their documentary: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption

I've tried several options, with quotes, without them... with "=" and with "eq" as their documentation says... Nothing goes.

Does anyone knows the answer??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office 365 APIs don't currently support filtering on complex types. `From` is a complex type unfortunately. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparameters: "Note You cannot use `$filter` with complex types."